# How can I easily score in PES 2014?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2014

With normal setting, (Xbox) how can I easily score 1 vs 1 , the goalkeeper always blocks my shoots, althoungh I use RT and shoot! , which direction of the joystick should I press? inclinated? justo up or down?

Sorry, not native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this years PES has many new mechanics so you should play all the training missions first to familiarize yourself with the new controls. There the new shooting mechanics are explained. I think you can also switch back to the classic PES mechanics if you're more familiar with them.

Further you should play it on an easier setting first... or play the free training with just the keeper and try 1-on-1 situations and experiment with all the shooting techniques aswell as tricks you can perform. 
I think there's no solution that works all the time, because the behavior of the keeper is always different aswell as your own speed, direction, position, player skill etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that PES 2014 already got an awesome artificial intelligence, so there is no such thing as "easy to score". Remember that it also depends on the skill of the player.